# callback's in Socket.IO-Client-Swift in objc project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sockets, socket.io

So my question is how callback works ?

i had imported the `[SocketIOClientSwift-Swift][1]` to my `[Objective-C]` project.
Here is my code:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://myserver.com:8080"];
SocketIOClient *socket = [[SocketIOClient alloc] initWithSocketURL:url options:@{ @"log": @YES, @"forcePolling": @YES }];

[socket onAny:^(SocketAnyEvent *event) {
  NSLog(@"Receive Event %@", event);
}];

[socket on:@"connect" callback:^(NSArray *data, SocketAckEmitter *ack) {
  NSLog(@"socket connected");
  // [socket emit:@"echo" withItems:@[@"echo test"]];
}];

[socket connect];
```

So I don't see any log with **Receive Event...** no callback's are called ,but if I uncomment the `[socket emit:@"echo" withItems:@[@"echo test"]];` , the callback is called and **Receive Event ...** log start displaying event if there is an **fail connection**. How ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like memory management issue. When you uncomment the line - you retain the **socket** object.  Try to explicitly retain **socket** object somewhere else (as a class member for instance). That should fix the problem.

Precisely saying, closure (block) retains outside objects which are used in the closure. You can read more here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

Especially relevant section to you is: "Blocks Can Capture Values from the Enclosing Scope". Hope it helps.

Just for issue troubleshooting could you try this:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://myserver.com:8080"];
SocketIOClient *socket = [[SocketIOClient alloc] initWithSocketURL:url options:@{ @"log": @YES, @"forcePolling": @YES }];

static SocketIOClient* __currentSocket = nil;
__currentSocket = socket;

[socket onAny:^(SocketAnyEvent *event) {
  NSLog(@"Receive Event %@", event);
}];

[socket on:@"connect" callback:^(NSArray *data, SocketAckEmitter *ack) {
  NSLog(@"socket connected");
}];

[socket connect];
```

Comment: @Constantin Saulenco can you try this?